# Setting Authentication in SecurityContext when using JWT

Tags: spring-security

I use Spring boot security for my server.
I added new filter that extends from OncePerRequestFilter and (according to many tutorials from the web) after validating the jwt save Authentication object into SecurityContext. 
What I don't understand is why do I need to save the Authentication in SecurityContext? after all I validate the jwt from the client in each request and don't need spring's to call isAuthenticated() on Authentication object.
Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security Authentication basically works by storing it in the `SecurityContext`. There is a `SecurityContextHolder` class which stores the `SecurityContext` and is used to many places where Authentication/Authorization decisions needs to be made by retrieving the `Authentication`. Even though you have validated the JWT to check the Authentication is success, Spring Security still needs `Authentication` object to make other decisions for example to evaluate `hasRole()`, `hasAnyRole()`, etc.

Comment: Do I also need to set to true  via setAuthenticated on Authentication object after I validate JWT?