# How stateless JWT authentication works in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am new to spring boot and coming from NodeJS (Javascript) background. In NodeJS we don't write much of code for JWT token creation and validation but in Spring boot I can see that we need to write a lot of code to make it working.

For past 4 days, I am researching on JWT implementation in Spring Boot which made me more confused. For eg, some of the tutorials and blogs on the web are fetching userDetails in a filter for each request. If we need to fetch userDetails for each subsequent request then we need to query the database for each request what's the need for the JWT implementation?

For example:

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Authorization

        String requestHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        //Bearer 2352345235sdfrsfgsdfsdf
        logger.info(" Header :  {}", requestHeader);
        String username = null;
        String token = null;
        if (requestHeader != null && requestHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            //looking good
            token = requestHeader.substring(7);
            try {

                username = this.jwtHelper.getUsernameFromToken(token);

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.info("Illegal Argument while fetching the username !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.info("Given jwt token is expired !!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                logger.info("Some changed has done in token !! Invalid Token");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        } else {
            logger.info("Invalid Header Value !! ");
        }


        //
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {


            //fetch user detail from username but why??
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            Boolean validateToken = this.jwtHelper.validateToken(token, userDetails);
            if (validateToken) {

                //set the authentication
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);


            } else {
                logger.info("Validation fails !!");
            }


        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
```

In the last `if` condition we can see that we are fetching user details to validate the token. Then what's the need for JWT if we need to query the database to validate the token?
Complete blog [here](https://www.learncodewithdurgesh.com/blogs/jwt-authentication-with-spring-boot-31)

Another doubt I have is why we need to set the user (after successful validation of token) in the security context of the application. We can see it in the above code.

I researched this and got this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59659822/setting-authentication-in-securitycontext-when-using-jwt) but still, I haven't got my doubt cleared.

So overall my doubts are:

1. Why we are fetching user details for each subsequent request? Isn't JWT stateless? Will it not create more load on the database for querying user details with each request?
2. Can't we set the user details like username, email, and authorities in the JWT payload altogether and extract this payload on validation? Then we don't need to query the database.
3. Why we need to set the user details in a security context? For eg., if our spring boot application is running on multiple docker containers then it's not important that the user request will get to the spring boot application which holds its principal, credentials, and authorities in the security context.
4. Is it important to use the in-built userDetails class for validation? Can't we have our own user details logic? Asking this because most of the YouTube tutorials use the userDetails class.

It would be great if someone could help me clear my doubts.

Thanks